# Multiple mysql users for different roles in one db

Tags: mysql, security

I was just wondering if it is safer to have different users for different tasks in a db. For example:
One user in one php file with the permission to select
One user in another php file with permission to select and update

That way, if a hacker somehow got access to the first user through the first php file, he/she would only be able to select.

Is it better to just use one user that can select and update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally best practice to have the minimum permission set required to perform any database task.

It is also best practice to not store usernames/passwords in the .php file. Instead store them in a configuration file outside of your version control.

Comment: Does that mean I should use multiple users to have the minimum permission for each task?

Comment: Yes. Depending how far you want to go, you're able to limit selection down to particular tables or views instead of across a schema.

Comment: If php is a server side language, why is it important to store the passwords outside of the file?

Comment: So... is that a YES to the original question then? If so, how do you switch users based on logins?